# Search table cell while hiding entire row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>
            Description<br>
            <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search description text">
        </td>
        <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td name="descSearch">It's a fruit</td>
        <td>Active</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pear</td>
        <td name="descSearch">It's also fruit</td>
        <td>No</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using some code to search the `description` column, and hide it when it doesn't contain what's being searched for. The problem is only the `td` is being hidden. I tried changing the selector to set `$row` but then it searched in all the cells I specified. How would I hide the entire row while only searching `description`? Here's what I'm using to search:

```
var $rows = $('td[name=descSearch]');
        $('#search').keyup(function() {
            var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

            $rows.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();
        });
```

Comment: The data populating in table is dynamic or some static data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently `$rows` is returned from this: `$('td[name=descSearch]')`, which is a collection of cells.  And that's ultimately what you're calling `.hide()` on.  Without changing the search logic, you can simply select the closest `<tr>` before calling `.hide()`.  To include the same logic in your `.show()` invocation you probably need to do it in two calls.

Something like this:

```
$rows.closest('tr').show();
$rows.filter(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
            return !~text.indexOf(val);
        }).closest('tr').hide();
```